# Using WPF for image display but have code in Winform?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is it possible to have a code (server and all that) in Winform and then instead of setting an image to a panel/picturebox, i can set it to WPF (which is faster?).

If so, will this operation be fast, or will it have to invoke or something which causes some delay in it?

I have tried doing this, settings an image on WPF from winform, sadly it wasn´t as easy as i expected.

Comment: What ***exactly*** are you trying to do?

Comment: Misses this. Well if you have seen my other posts, i am trying desperately to find a way to display images fast. And SlimDX isn´t going my way. So i am trying my luck in WPF. So in other words, i want to display images very fast, and it should be able ti withstand higher resolutions (Panel and Picturebox slow down at 800x600+).

Comment: For your specific intent of displaying images very fast, please consider looking for or posting a new question,

Comment: Well, i have asked it before, but i get no answer. So i guess i must be more specific, as Faster is quite the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a Windows Forms project and was able to
: create new WPF pages
: add WPF controls to existing Windows Forms

First of all you need to change you .csproj in order to have the option of creating a new WPF page and control available. I do not know now by heart, but basically it's a GUID you add.

From what i read you want the second. While on the Windows Forms designer you can just go to you toolbox and drop a WPF control into the Windows Forms. By doing so VS creates to things:
1. Your wpf control
2. ElementHost control

You can then access your wpf control just as usual by accessing its variable name.

Comment: Are you talking about that (WPF integration) thing in the toolbox? cause i wanted to get it working. I followed as stated, i created a WPF project and user control, added it to reference, but it still wasn´t available to choose from.

Comment: I did it some time ago. Try here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [WindowsFormHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx)  It allows you to utilize WinForm controls in a WPF application.  It still renders through GDI though.  If you want it to utilize WPF, you could pass the data you use to render the image up to WPF.

Comment: What i wans is the second one, IF it´s faster.